# IntelliJ & JRuby: how to setup project?

Tags: intellij-idea, jruby

I've downloaded a trial version of IntelliJ 13 and I've installed the latest JRuby version for Windows.

I've searched thoroughly on the net, but have been unable to find any guidance as to how to setup a JRuby project in IntelliJ. I've chosen IntelliJ as opposed to RubyMine as it should have better support for Java/Ruby integration (see http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1146).

So in short; how do I setup IntelliJ for a JRuby project - perhaps just a simple hello world example?

Answer (score 3):

so in short words, create new project, the select java, then hit next, on the next page select jruby and you should be all set

if your project is created already my configuration in general looks like

project  -> sdk java
module -> new module -> java -> jruby

this should automatically create a facet with jruby stuff and the syntax highlighting should work

hope it helps

Comment: Is that all you have to do? I have JRuby as a facet in my project but when I write `java.lang.System.out.println("test")` (after requiring java of course) it underlines `System`, marks it as a warning and says `Cannot find 'System'`. Any idea why it doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 1):

I found out you need to install the Ruby plugin for IntelliJ first (http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=1293). After that there are options to create JRuby projects.