# IntelliJ + JRuby: missing arguments on Java methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jruby

**Note:** Please scroll down to my edit as my primary problem is solved.

I'm trying do set up IntelliJ with the Ruby plugin in order to work with JRuby (referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032930/intellij-jruby-how-to-setup-project) question). My problem in sepcific:

```
puts 'this is ruby'

require 'java'
java.lang.System.out.println('this is java')  # works, but "Cannot find System"
```

The code snippet above does work when I run the script from IntelliJ but it underlines `System` as a warning and says `Cannot find 'System'`.
JRuby is added to my project configurations in section Facet.
[image: this is how it looks like]

What do I have to do to get IntelliJ recognizing the Java code in my JRuby code properly?

**Edit:** I changed the project SDK from JRuby to Java 1.8. It finds the Java methods now but on each method which takes at least one parameter it says `Missing x arguments` or `Found x extra arguments`.

[image: new error]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I installed JRuby via rvm and used it as the SDK in my project and it all seems to work.  There is a bit of latency in intellij when recognizing the java classes and methods but after a second or two the squiggly lines go away.

[image]

Comment: So you don't get these `missing argument` errors e.g. when adding a JPanel to a JFrame? It finds the Java methods now but if they're overloaded it finds only one definition.

Comment: I just added in your JLabel example with the java_import and it seemed to work.  Have you tried running the configuration.  If it does not run the errors may be helpful in debugging the issue.

Comment: The example works indeed when I run it but IntelliJ marks the `add` method as an error anyways. I uploaded a few screenshots what my configuration look like: http://imgur.com/a/s29GE

Comment: My project also uses the JRuby facet, but additionally my SDK is my  current jruby install.